# AFNetworking shows the Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I am trying to update the AFNetworking package from version 2 to the latest version 4. While updating I am getting the below error.

Note: I am trying to update version 2 to version 4. Here I am using the git repo and linked the frameworks manually. Not using the pods.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LiteExtensionEngine.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONResponseSerializer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LiteExtensionEngine.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)



Showing All Errors Only
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager

Showing All Errors Only
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONResponseSerializer
 cd /Users/name/
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target arm64-apple-ios11.0-simulator -isysroot 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk -L/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-cjpgnnljisqaxreuglmwhasmpyfd/Build/Products/Debug-
iphonesimulator -F/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/naem-filelist /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-cjpgnnljisqaxreuglmwhasmpyfd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SummaryExtension.build/Objects-
normal/arm64/SummaryExtension.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../../Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-cjpgnnljisqaxreuglmwhasmpyfd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SummaryExtension.build/Objects-
normal/arm64/SummaryExtension_lto.o -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -fapplication-extension -e _NSExtensionMain -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -
Xliibrary/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-cjpgnnljisqaxreuglmwhasmpyfd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SummaryExtension.build/SummaryExtension.appex-Simulated.xcent -framework NotificationCenter -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-cjpgnnljisqaxreuglmwhasmpyfd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Project.build/Debug-
iphonesimulator/SummaryExtension.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SummaryExtension_dependency_info.dat -o 
Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-cjpgnnljisqaxreuglmwhasmpyfd/Build/Products/Debug-SummaryExtension.appex/SummaryExtension
```